# How to block a website in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, blocking

I need to block a couple of websites in Google Chrome. I don't want to edit my hosts file, because I want to get to those sites from other browsers.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

[Block Websites Buddy](http://www.scosoft.com/block-web-site-buddy.htm) claims to work with Google Chrome. I'm not sure if the site will be blocked in the other browsers as well however.

[image]

Comment: Windows only, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 0):

The [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) extension will block all images from a certain site, but it won't block the site content.

[Blockit](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dfjfhdfdeogiplgepcbfjcpiianmeoed) will block entire websites, but it's a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

[Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)

```
The personal blocklist extension will transmit to Google the patterns that you choose to block. When you choose to block or unblock a pattern, the extension will also transmit to Google the URL of the web page on which the blocked or unblocked search results are displayed. You agree that Google may freely use this information to improve our products and services.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome you will gets extensions from the Chrome Store. Go to Store and search for BlockSite extension. Add it to your Chrome. It works fine. I used it before.